# Setting pretty print tags through javascript

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, pretty-print

Im trying to get pretty.js to prettify code in CODE tags, using this js:

```
onload_functions.push(function() {
    var node_list=document.getElementsByTagName('code');
    for (i=0; i < node_list.length; i++) {
        node_list[i].setAttribute('class','prettyprint');
    }
    prettyPrint();
});
```

This works fine for Firefox :) but IE's having none of it.
What am i doing wrong?

You can see it (non)working at http://sam.xnet.tk

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the code element has any other class names, this will yield chaos in IE. Using the (IE-specific) JavaScript property `className` will likely work.
I commented on the `onload` function on your website.
Btw, the way you embed the JavaScript it will break future standard-compatible browsers, see the [W3C validator's output for your site](http://validator.w3.org/check?verbose=1&uri=http%3A%2F%2Fsam.xnet.tk%2F). The easiest solution is to move the code to an external file.

Comment: Yep, className is IE only.  Standards-compliant browsers use class.

Answer (score 2):

This would be far simple and work in all browsers with jQuery.

```
$(function() {
    $('code').addClass('prettyprint');
    prettyPrint();
});
```

EDIT: The reason it's not working in IE is because IE uses 'className' instead of 'class' just to make life miserable.

Comment: I think i may have to use jquery, was holding off because its another 50Kb people must download to view the page.

Comment: Hm, according to the jQuery site it's only 15kb.  

Also take a look at this article: http://encosia.com/2008/12/10/3-reasons-why-you-should-let-google-host-jquery-for-you/

If you let google host it, then a user won't need to download it if they've ever visited a site that did the same.